# How to get a flip effect on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-effects

I want to get like a jQuery UI effect that flips a div.

An example would be clicking "forgot password" on this site:
https://drive.jolicloud.com/welcome

You will notice the whole signup div flips to the back of it.

How would I achieve this effect?

Comment: what things have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

They are using [Flippant](http://labs.mintchaos.com/flippant.js/), very simple and cool. Its mostly based on CSS transform effects and animations.

I highly recommend this option over the use of a jQuery plugin if you just want to flip things  back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this should qualify as an answer or comment, but check out http://lab.smashup.it/flip/ . I think the amount of code required to create a cross browser flipping effect is a little too much to ask without trying yourself and getting close

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple and crude flip effect, you could just animate the width to zero, swap the content, then animate the width back to its original value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple animation using CSS

http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Basically you create a front and back div in a container. Rotate the back one 180 degrees over the Y axis. When you want to flip, you rotate the container 180 degrees. Add smooth transition and your done.